# least squares curve fitting

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares

I have a set of distances **x=c*r/rs**

```
 array([ 0.09317335,  0.1863467 ,  0.27952006,  0.37269341,  0.46586676,
        0.55904011,  0.65221346,  0.74538682,  0.83856017,  0.93173352,
        1.02490687,  1.11808022,  1.21125357,  1.30442693,  1.39760028,
        1.49077363,  1.58394698,  1.67712033,  1.77029369,  1.86346704])
```

and **number density (sigma)**
 `array([  9.56085037e+14,   5.13431506e+14,   3.26960286e+14,
         2.27865084e+14,   1.68325130e+14,   1.29590176e+14,
         1.02918831e+14,   8.37487042e+13,   6.94971037e+13,
         5.86086377e+13,   5.00994710e+13,   4.33218850e+13,
         3.78349864e+13,   3.33300619e+13,   2.95856349e+13,
         2.64394232e+13,   2.37702922e+13,   2.14863249e+13,
         1.95167455e+13,   1.78063354e+13])`

which I have plotted to get the following graph. It is a log log plot.[image]

I have a function [image]

which should fit my graph according to theory. I don't how to use `scipy.opt.leastsquare` to use the function and fit my graph. The parameters to fit are `c` and `rs`

Comment: Awesome write-up with graphs and formulas.

Comment: Your model function has no parameters except for a constant factor, what do you want to fit, just the factor??

Comment: @Nabla Actually, x=c*r/rs, wherein c and rs are the parameters i need to fit

Comment: This might be a good starting point for you [Non-linear optimization with scipy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942153/how-to-perform-non-linear-optimization-with-scipy-numpy-or-sympy)

Comment: @srivatsan Is your data `x` and `Sigma(x)` or `r` and `Sigma(r)`? Even if the second is the case, you are left with only two degrees of freedom and those are equivalent to axis rescaling. Anyway, if you have a recent version of scipy you can use [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit) instead, which will take care of sum stuff like error calculation. The example should explain the use.

Comment: Is your `y` axis label correct? What does `MPC` stand for?

Comment: @Nabla sorry for the axis of the graph.. It is actually x and Sigma(x). I am only confused as to how to include that Sigma function as it has three conditions.

Comment: @srivatsan But if you only have `x` and `Sigma(x)` then you cannot fit the parameter `c` because `Sigma(x)` does not depend on it. You only can fit `r_s` if `delta_c` and `rho_c` are constants. Also you write `Sigma(x)` as a normal python function, you can use `if` for the different conditions.

Comment: @CTZhu `Mpc` probably stands for Megaparsec, a distance measure in astronomy.

Comment: @CTZhu yes as Nabla points out, it does stand for Megaparsec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Using scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Option 2: write your own function to output R2 or sse, then minimize this function using scipy.optimize. I've always used this method for complicated problems and would recommend the algorithms of SLSQP and L-BFGS-B.