# Non convex optimizer

Tags: python-2.7, optimization, scipy

I use python2.7 and need to find the maximum of a multivariate scalar function.

In other words I have this function:

```
def myFun(a,b,c,d,e,f):
    # complex calculation that takes about 30 seconds
    return res # res is a float
```

This function is NOT convex.

I specify the min and max possible value for each argument a, b, c, d, e and f. I need to find what combination of argument approximately result in the maximum value for `myFun`. I will feed it a decent starting point.

I tried doing a brute force grid search but given how long my function takes to compute, it is not viable.

I have looked into the scipy package. I saw in particular the [`scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp.html) function. Would that be appropriate for my problem? Or maybe [`scipy.optimize.fmin()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html)?
Is there any other function/module that is appropriate for this?

Comment: One important thing to know is if you have good derivatives or not. Of you have gradients then a solver using them is probably a good idea. If no derivatives are available, you need to look into a derivative-free algorithm. Also do you want a global solution or is a local optimizer good enough?

Comment: A local optimizer is good enough. I do not have a gradient, my function is too complex for me to mathematically derive something on paper, let alone implement it.

Comment: I would start with the derivative free methods Powell and Nelder-Mead. If you need more performance have a look at the [paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10898-012-9951-y) by Rios and Sahinidis. Disclaimer: I am not an expert in derivative free methods.

Comment: Another derivative-free approach for costly evaluations is [rbfopt](https://projects.coin-or.org/RBFOpt/wiki)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might want to try CVXPY (http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest), which is oddly enough a non-convex extension of CVXOPT (a convex solver).  Then you can do convex optimization with CVXOPT or non-convex with CVXPY, whatever suits you for the problem.

There are a bunch of non-convex solvers in python, and many of them are listed here: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/83/is-there-a-high-quality-nonlinear-programming-solver-for-python... but it seems you are actually asking about a continuous solver, which may be local or global, and can handle expensive functions.

Personally, I'd suggest `mystic` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mystic).  True, I'm the author, but it's been decently funded for about a decade, and it can address highly-constrained non-convex problems that are pretty unsolvable with other packages.  It can also handle fundamentally convex optimization with nonlinear constraints.  Also, `mystic` is built for massively parallel computing, so you can easily leverage parallel computing in your optimizations at several levels.  If you have enough resources, `mystic` can do an ensemble optimization, which you can imagine like being able to do a grid search (where you can pick the initial distribution of points), and instead of using fixed points on a grid, `mystic` uses fast linear solvers launched in parallel.

Here's one of the nearly 100 examples that come with `mystic`:

```
'''
    Maximize: f = 2*x[0]*x[1] + 2*x[0] - x[0]**2 - 2*x[1]**2

    Subject to:    x[0]**3 - x[1] == 0
                             x[1] >= 1
'''
```

Two solutions are presented (one for a linear solver, and one a global solver):

```
def objective(x):
    return 2*x[0]*x[1] + 2*x[0] - x[0]**2 - 2*x[1]**2

equations = """
x0**3 - x1 == 0.0
"""
bounds = [(None, None),(1.0, None)]

# with penalty='penalty' applied, solution is:
xs = [1,1]; ys = -1.0

from mystic.symbolic import generate_conditions, generate_penalty
pf = generate_penalty(generate_conditions(equations), k=1e4)
from mystic.symbolic import generate_constraint, generate_solvers, solve
cf = generate_constraint(generate_solvers(solve(equations)))

# inverted objective, used in solving for the maximum
_objective = lambda x: -objective(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':

  from mystic.solvers import diffev2, fmin_powell
  from mystic.math import almostEqual

  result = diffev2(_objective, x0=bounds, bounds=bounds, constraint=cf, penalty=pf, npop=40, ftol=1e-8, gtol=100, disp=False, full_output=True)
  assert almostEqual(result[0], xs, rel=2e-2)
  assert almostEqual(result[1], ys, rel=2e-2)

  result = fmin_powell(_objective, x0=[-1.0,1.0], bounds=bounds, constraint=cf, penalty=pf, disp=False, full_output=True)
  assert almostEqual(result[0], xs, rel=2e-2)
  assert almostEqual(result[1], ys, rel=2e-2)
```

Here's another:

```
"""
    Fit linear and quadratic polynomial to noisy data:
               y(x) ~ a + b * x   --or--   y(x) ~ a + b * x + c * x**2
    where:
               0 >= x >= 4
               y(x) = y0(x) + yn
               y0(x) = 1.5 * exp(-0.2 * x) + 0.3
               yn = 0.1 * Normal(0,1)
"""
```

With solution(s):

```
from numpy import polyfit, poly1d, linspace, exp
from numpy.random import normal
from mystic.math import polyeval
from mystic import reduced

# Create clean data.
x = linspace(0, 4.0, 100)
y0 = 1.5 * exp(-0.2 * x) + 0.3

# Add a bit of noise.
noise = 0.1 * normal(size=100) 
y = y0 + noise

@reduced(lambda x,y: abs(x)+abs(y))
def objective(coeffs, x, y):
    return polyeval(coeffs, x) - y

bounds = [(None, None), (None, None), (None, None)]
args = (x, y)

# 'solution' is:
xs = polyfit(x, y, 2) 
ys = objective(xs, x, y)


if __name__ == '__main__':

  from mystic.solvers import diffev2, fmin_powell
  from mystic.math import almostEqual

  result = diffev2(objective, args=args, x0=bounds, bounds=bounds, npop=40, ftol=1e-8, gtol=100, disp=False, full_output=True)
  assert almostEqual(result[0], xs, tol=1e-1)
  assert almostEqual(result[1], ys, rel=1e-1)

  result = fmin_powell(objective, args=args, x0=[0.0,0.0,0.0], bounds=bounds, disp=False, full_output=True)
  assert almostEqual(result[0], xs, tol=1e-1)
  assert almostEqual(result[1], ys, rel=1e-1)
```

For parallel computing, `mystic` can leverage `pathos` and `pyina` (see: https://github.com/uqfoundation for both), where you just pass the hierarchical configuration of map functions that you want to use to run in parallel. It's pretty easy.  It may not be the fastest for a stock problem, but it is (in my opinion) the best choice for problems that you can't solve otherwise (due to size or complexity).

Comment: I didn't realize this was possible and it doesn't seem to be mentioned on the CVXPY website. Would it be possible then, to solve non-convex problems using, say,  IPOPT or SNOPT in the CVXPY framework?

Comment: @indigoblue: the code above is from `mystic` not `CVXPY`.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns: I am interested in using mystic, but I cannot find the tutorial mentioned in the example README (which says "Examples with prefix "example" are part of the tutorial").

Comment: The examples from the tutorial are here: https://github.com/uqfoundation/mystic/tree/master/examples (the tutorial itself is on a legacy website, still accessible but unnecessary).  Newer tutorials are here: https://github.com/mmckerns/tlkmys, and  https://github.com/mmckerns/tutmom;

Comment: Hi @MikeMcKerns do you have an example for a problem that has a function in its objective function? For example assume you want to max x1 * f(x2) subject to some constraints. x1 and x2 are your decision variables and function f can not be written as an equation. But you can implement it in python.

Comment: @ShahroozPooryousef: I think you'd just need something like this: `objective = lambda x: -(x[0] * f(x[1]))`, which then an optimizer could maximize.

Comment: Thanks @MikeMcKerns, That is almost what I need. Except that my variables have three dimensions. For example, instead of having two variables x0 and x1, I have w[t][k][p] and n[t][k][p] where t, k, and p belong to sets T, K, and P respectively. And I want to maximize the average of w[t][k][p]*f(n[t][k][p])over set T, K, and P which would be 1/|T| *1/|K| * 1/|P| * w[t][k][p] * f(n[t][k][p]). I know it is too much and I need to read a little about how to implement this, but can you please help me with that also? That would really be a great help. Thanks.

Comment: Is this what you are asking: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72835244/2379433?

Comment: @MikeMcKerns yes :). I have tried to explain my problem formulation there in more detail.

Answer (score 4):

I had to perform a non-convex optimization recently. I used the [L-BFGS method from scipy.optimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b.html). It worked well enough for my purposes. You can find more information [here](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/mathematical_optimization/#practical-guide-to-optimization-with-scipy) about choosing an optimizer relevant for your purposes. The L-BFGS function in scipy.optimize can approximate the gradient for you as well, since your function is too complex to find the gradient.