# Scipy - Non-linear Equations System with linear constraints (beginner)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, equation-solving, nonlinear-functions

I have seen this [amazing example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739227/how-to-solve-a-pair-of-nonlinear-equations-using-python).
But I need to solve system with boundaries on X and F, for example:

```
    f1 = x+y^2 = 0
    f2 = e^x+ xy = 0
-5.5< x <0.18
2.1< y < 10.6
   # 0.15< f1 <20.5 - not useful for this example
   # -10.5< f2 < -0.16 - not useful for this example
```

How could I set this boundary constrains to fsolve() of scipy? Or may be there is some other method?
Would You give me a Simple code example?

Comment: How can you solve for `f1 = 0` when there is a constraint `f1 > 0.15`?

Comment: Google: Scipy &  constraint nonlinear optimization. Use e.g scipy.optimize.minimize

Comment: Dear @Moritz, of course, I have searched for my question in Google before I asked You. But there were no useful solution for me, which I would be able to understood. Therefore I asked You for simple example.

Comment: @Moritz, And, for sure, I looked at the page of [scipy.optimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html), but What is the difference between .minimize and .fsolve? It looks, like .minimize is for problem like F=(f1,f2,..)->min (that is more seems to be (df/dx=0) problem), not for equation systems, as represented above. What is way to use .minimize for Non-LAE systems?

Comment: @cfh, thank you, I just was thinking about my own system-problem, and do not thought, what this simple example do not need any constraints to satisfy because it's f(x)=const problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the system, but here you can simply check the constraints afterwards.

First solve your nonlinear system to get one/none/several solutions of the form (x,y). Then check which, if any, of these solutions, satisfy the constraints.

Comment: Yes, I also was thinking about it also. And, guess, this could be the simplest way.

Answer (score 4):

I hope this will serve you as a starter. It was all [there](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def my_fun(z):
    x = z[0]
    y = z[1]

    f = np.zeros(2)
    f[0] = x + y ** 2
    f[1] = np.exp(x) + x * y
    return np.dot(f,f)

def my_cons(z):
    x = z[0]
    y = z[1]
    f = np.zeros(4)
    f[0] = x + 5.5
    f[1] = 0.18 - x
    f[2] = y - 2.1
    f[3] = 10.6 - y
    return f

cons = {'type' : 'ineq', 'fun': my_cons}
res = minimize(my_fun, (2, 0), method='SLSQP',\
           constraints=cons)
res
```

`status: 0
 success: True
    njev: 7
    nfev: 29
     fun: 14.514193585986144
       x: array([-0.86901099,  2.1       ])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     jac: array([ -2.47001648e-04,   3.21871972e+01,   0.00000000e+00])
     nit: 7`

EDIT: As a response to the comments: If your function values `f1` and `f2` are not zero you just have to rewrite the equations e.g:

f1 = -6 and f2 = 3

Your function to minimize will be:

```
def my_fun(z):
    x = z[0]
    y = z[1]

    f = np.zeros(2)
    f[0] = x + y ** 2 + 6
    f[1] = np.exp(x) + x * y -3
    return np.dot(f,f)
```

Comment: But this does minimization, OP wants to solve a system of equation. How does this help?

Comment: So what ? Maybe I do not understand the concept of solving system of equations but he would like to find values for x and y which do fulfill the constraints and the system clearly should be minimized `f[0] = 0 and f[1] = 0`. You can write every system of equation in a way that the residual should be zero.

Comment: Why do you think that (0,0) is the minimum of the system? The values f1 and f2 might get negative.

Comment: He wrote `f1=0` and `f2=0`

Comment: You don't gain anything from rewriting it as a constrained optimization problem: if the optimization reaches 0 (which it doesn't in your case), then you have found a solution, but the constraints aren't active and you could have simply solved the equation without constraints anyway. If you don't reach 0, you haven't found a solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78570/discussion-between-moritz-and-cfh).