# Solve nonlinear equation on segment

Tags: python, scipy, sympy

I am looking for a function which solves trigonometric equation on a given segment.

I've tried [fsolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html) from scipy, but as I understood, there is not such option, just only the initial approximation point.

Does python have such a library method anywhere? Also I've looked at [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html), but did not find any appropriate solutions there.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378861/scipy-non-linear-equations-system-with-linear-constraints-beginner

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a root of a function in a given range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43271440/find-a-root-of-a-function-in-a-given-range)

Answer (score 0):

For a single scalar equation, use `brentq`

```
In [1]: from scipy.optimize import brentq

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: brentq(np.sin, np.pi+1, 2*np.pi+1)
Out[3]: 6.28318530718002
```

For systems of equations, use `least_squares` to minimize the sum of squares of left hand sides of the equations.