# Scipy - All the Solutions of Non-linear Equations System

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, equation-solving, nonlinear-functions

I have a system of non-linear equations, where can be choosed any *n*, so length of vector *x = (x1,...,xn)* can be different. For example, system can be like that:

```
    f1(x1,...,xn) = sum( xi + xi^2 ) = 0, i={1,n}
    f2(x1,...,xn) = sum( e^xi + xi + sin(xi*pi) ) = 0, i={1,n}
```

According to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739227/how-to-solve-a-pair-of-nonlinear-equations-using-python), I use fsolve() of scipy library for solving such a NLE, but it returns only one solution for every single initial approximation of *x = x0. But as *n* can be large (for example, *n = 100*), and there can be a lot of solutions, so it's not very usefull to make initial conditions *x = x0* for finding every solution.

So, please, could You give me an example, how to find ***All*** the solutions by fsolve() in such a situation? Or by any other simple method?

***Additional***
For example, I have folloving simple system:

```
def equations(p):
    x, y = p
    return (x**2-1, x**3-1)
```

With different initial condiotions I have different solutions:
    x, y =  fsolve(equations, (0, 0))
    (0.0, 0.0)

```
x, y =  fsolve(equations, (1, 1))
(1.0, 1.0)

x, y =  fsolve(equations, (-1, 1))
(-0.47029706057873205, 0.41417128904566508)
```

Is it possible to use any Scipy-function, like fsolve(), to find All the solutions (roots), for example:
    x, y =  some_scipy_solver(equations, (x0, y0))
    1. (1.0, 1.0)
    2. (0.0, 0.0)
    3. (-0.47029706057873205, 0.41417128904566508)
    ...

where (x0, y0) = any initial approximation:(0, 0),(1, 1),(-1, 1),(0.1, 10.0), etc, and where I determine just the constraints for x0, y0, like that: -1.0 <= x0 < 1.0, 0.0 <= x0 < 11.0.

Comment: P.S. I have already implemented systems of functions, which I need, like <def sys1():{ f1 = ... ; f2 = ... ; return (f0, f1, ); }>, and module to solve those systems by using fsolve(sys1, x0). So it would be very helpfull, if You'll give me example with fsolve() as well or with method, which can simply replace fsolve((f1, f2), x0) or fsolve([f1, f2], x0).

Answer (score 3):

It can be difficult (or impossible ) to find numerically all the solutions even for a single non-linear equation, let along a system. For instance, consider the equation,

```
sin(1/x) = 0
```

that has an infinity of solutions in the interval `[0, 1]`: you can't solve this with typical root-finding algorithms.

In particular, `scipy.optimize.fsolve` uses local optimization approaches  to find one solution of the given equation. Conceptually, you can't use it (or anything else in `scipy` module, really)  to find all the possible solutions.  Of course, if you know that the system has a given number of solutions, you can just randomly set the initial conditions to `fsolve` (as you have done) until you find all of them. There is no general method that would work for this problem though.

Instead, you might have better luck in solving your system analytically with [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/solvers/solvers.html#sympy.solvers.solve), if it is simple enough.

Comment: I have already heard about sympy and I've tried sympy.nsolve, which worked the same way as fsolve from scipy. So now I should try to use sympy.solve, Thank You for advice!

As I understood, sympy.solve does not gives the numerical solutions (only analitical functions as a root), does it?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. `sympy.solve` returns the analytical roots, and should give you all the solutions.

Comment: Unfortunately, analitical roots as ___x1 = f(x2)___ doesn't support my needs. I need only numerical solution - the final result, which I want to get, should be a grathical plot of ___f1(x1,...,xn) = F(f2(x1,...,xn))___. So, I just want to get set of points _(x1,...,xn)[1], ..., (x1,...,xn)[m]_, solved numerically, and plot set of points _(f1(x1,...,xn)[1], f2(x1,...,xn)[1]), ..., (f1(x1,...,xn)[m], f2(x1,...,xn)[m])_.

Answer (score 0):

with `ipywidgets` you can do.  Root will change inetractively in range -100 .. 100

```
def root_finder(x):
    print('Root is %.3f' %fsolve(funct,x))
    
widgets.interact(root_finder,x=(-100,100,0.5));
```