# Solve for constants of 4-parameter (Rodbard Equation) using Python

Tags: python, variables, scipy, nonlinear-functions, equations

I am new to python and what I am trying to do is write an algorithm to solve for the 4 unknown parameters in the Rodbard Equation where we are relating a grayscale value measured using ImageJ to optical density calibration discs.  This equation is nonlinear and is written as y = c*((x-a)/(d-x))^(1/b) where a, b, c, and d are unknown.  I have the values of x and y for four point (176.5, 0), (161.333, 0.1), (66.1667, 0.9), and (40.833, 2.5).  Below, I have posted my attempt to solve for these 4 unknowns.  Any help to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

```
    import scipy.optimize as opt

    def f(a, b, c, d):
         0 == [c * ((176.5 - a)/(d - 176.5))**(1/b)]
         0.1 == [c * ((161.333 - a)/(d - 161.333))**(1/b)]
         0.9 == [c * ((66.1667 - a)/(d - 66.1667))**(1/b)]
         2.5 == [c * ((40.833 - a)/(d - 40.833))**(1/b)]
    return f

    opt.curve_fit(a, b, c, d)

    print a
    print b
    print c
    print d
```

Comment: I tried editing it by following the example but it is still not working for me.  Sorry I couldn't get it to come up like code but here it is:   import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
def func(x, a, b, c, d):
    return [c * ((x - a)/(d - x))**(1/b)]
    
xdata = np.linspace(0, 1, 255)
y = func(xdata, 0, 0.1, 0.9, 2.5)
ydata = y + 0.2 * np.random.normal(size=len(xdata))
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use curve_fit, you should do the following:

```
def f(x1, a1, b1, c1, d1):
    return c1 * (((x1 - a1)/(d1 - x1))**1/b1)

x_data = np.array([176.5, 161.333, 66.1667, 40.833])
y_data = np.array([0., 0.1, 0.9, 2.5])
p0 = np.array([168., -0.01, -7.4, 35000.])

popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(f, x_data, y_data, p0, None, False, True, ftol = 0.00001)
```

p0 is the initial guess and if you do not inform it, an array of all ones will be assumed.

With the provided data I have tried with different params but I've not been able to find a solution.

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: I tried this but I keep get errors, this is what I have now where p0 is close to what the actual value is:  import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt

def f(x1, a1, b1, c1, d1):
    return c1 * (((x1 - a1)/(d1 - x1))**(1/b1))

x_data = np.array([169.85, 172.15, 42.68, 65.13])
y_data = np.array([0.03, 0., 2.5, 0.9])
p0 = np.array([34., -1.5, 0.5, 170.])

popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(f, x_data, y_data, p0, None, False, True, ftol = 0.00001)

Comment: Even know I know these values produce an r-squared value of 1 it says... Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 1000.  Would I need to change ftol?

Comment: I think the optimization of this function is problematic because the base of the exponentiation can have negative values. If you use p0=np.array([15., -1./1.5, 0.5, 180.]) the base is positive for all observed x values and curve_fit converges (with warnings) to a quite good solution: [  21.63157788   -0.77630377    0.53499971  176.50006451]

Comment: Thank you so much!  This actually produces something I was expecting!

Answer (score 0):

This looks similar to this question: [How to solve a pair of nonlinear equations using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739227/how-to-solve-a-pair-of-nonlinear-equations-using-python)

But this does not seem to give me the correct answer. Try copying this and adding more points?

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def equations(p):
    a,b,c,d = p
    return ((c * ((176.5-a)/(d-176.5))**(1/b)),
            (c * ((161.333-a)/(d-161.333))**(1/b))-0.1,
            (c * ((66.1667-a)/(d-66.1667))**(1/b))-0.9,
            (c * ((40.833-a)/(d-40.833))**(1/b))-2.5)

a,b,c,d = fsolve(equations, (1,1,1,1))
print a,b,c,d
```

output:

```
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

Comment: I added more but I could get the bottom portion to work: (c * ((131.5-a)/(d-131.5))**(1/b))-0.3,
            (c * ((115.1667-a)/(d-115.1667))**(1/b))-0.4,
            (c * ((91.333-a)/(d-91.333))**(1/b))-0.6,
            (c * ((175.333-a)/(d-175.333))**(1/b))-0.03,
            (c * ((174.333-a)/(d-174.333))**(1/b))-0.05,
            (c * ((154.333-a)/(d-154.333))**(1/b))-0.15,

Comment: Would it be easier to use SymPy?

Comment: a,b,c,d = fsolve(equations, (1,1,1,1))

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I see yeah it looks like you can't do overdetermined with that fsolve function. Try this one then? (from the same thread as before) http://stackoverflow.com/a/8954984/5889975

Comment: I tried this: from sympy import nsolve
nsolve([c * ((176.5-a)/(d-176.5))**(1/b), c * ((66.1667-a)/(d-66.1667))**(1/b)-0.9, c * ((40.833-a)/(d-40.833))**(1/b)-2.5, c * ((115.1667-a)/(d-115.1667))**(1/b)-0.4], [a, b, c, d], [22, -1.5, 0.5, 175]), now I get an error saying a, b, c, d are not defined even though I know the values [22, -1.5, 0.5, 175] are close to what the values should be.