# How to solve multi-variable simultaneous equations numerically with some variables known?

Tags: python, scipy, equation-solving

[How to solve a pair of nonlinear equations using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739227/how-to-solve-a-pair-of-nonlinear-equations-using-python)
In this question a pair of nonlinear equations that each has two arguments were solved.

Now I have more than two equations, each has a number of arguments. The number of arguments is more than the number of equations.

By using the method in the question.
eg:

```
'''
def func0(a,b,c,d,local1=α,local2=β):
    #process
    return function
# func0==0
def func1():
    return
#etc

def multi_equ(p):
    a,b,c,d,e = p
    return (func0(a,b,c,d,local1,local2),func1(c,d,e),func2(a,b,c,d,e,local),etc)
'''
```

My question is:

How to write the fsolve() to solve such function when, for example, sometime argument c is known, I am trying to solve the rests.

Comment: fsolve() seems requiring some sense of order. I am thinking to write a wrap function changing the arguments order in multi_equ(). Is there a better way, or other function can replace fsolve()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use [`fsolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html), you need

> A function that takes at least one (possibly vector) argument, and returns a value **of the same length**.

So, the number of equations must be equal to the number of unknowns. If you have a function that takes similar input, except that one of the input variables is known, then wrap it in another function, like this:

```
def f(a, b, c, d): 
    return [a-b, b-c, c-d] 

def func(p):
    a, b, d = p
    c = 0.5
    return f(a, b, c, d)
```

Here `func` is suitable to be used in `fsolve`, for example

```
fsolve(func, [0, 0, 0])   # returns [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
```

#### Number of unknowns different from the number of equations

If the mathematical problems has more (or fewer) unknowns than equations, then `fsolve` cannot be used. The tool I would use then is [`least_squares`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html#scipy.optimize.least_squares) which minimizes the sum of squares of `func`.

```
def func(p):
    a, b, c, d = p
    return [a-b, b-c, c-d] 

least_squares(func, [3, 2, 5, 1])
```

This finds a solution of least-squares problem as `[2.75, 2.75, 2.75, 2.75]`. It also returns the cost which, being nearly zero, tells us that `func` indeed turns to zero at the point that was found. This solution is not unique.