# How to solve system of non-linear equations?

Tags: python, scipy, polynomials, equation-solving, nonlinear-functions

I am trying to solve a system of non-linear equations as follows in Python:

A-B*x1^4+C(x2-x1)+C+D=0

E(x1-x2)+F(x3-x2)+G(x3^4-x2^4)+I=0

J(x2-x3)+K(x4-x3)+L(x3^4-x2^4)+M=0

N-P*x4^4+Q(x3-x4)+R+S=0

where x1,x2,x3,x4 are the 4 unknowns and A, B, C,...., S either depends as a function of some input values or constant values.

I am trying to find the values of x1,x2,x3,x4.

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research and what went wrong with your attempts?

Comment: Hi, I am not aware of any method for that, I created the functions from a scientific reference. As per them, they solved it linearizing them and converting it to a matrix format, thus I was looking for any Pythonic way to easily solve them in non-linear approach itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve a pair of nonlinear equations using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739227/how-to-solve-a-pair-of-nonlinear-equations-using-python)