# How to solve a non-linear system in Python

Tags: python, equation-solving, nonlinear-functions

I have three different 3D equations and i want to get the intersection between them (the solution of the system). My variables are x,y,z

Equations:

```
-0.006683 x**2 - 0.06893 x + 56.73- z = 0
0.002538 y**2 - 1.115 y + 56.73 - z = 0
(x-24.680)**2+(y-238.341)**2+(z+13.971)**2 = 12.580**2
```

How can i solve this nonlinear system in python?

Comment: Analytically or numerically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve a pair of nonlinear equations using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739227/how-to-solve-a-pair-of-nonlinear-equations-using-python)

Comment: @warped has a nicer solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you re-write the functions:

```
-0.006683 x**2 - 0.06893 x + 56.73- z = 0
0.002538 y**2 - 1.115 y + 56.73 - z = 0
(x-24.680)**2+(y-238.341)**2+(z+13.971)**2 - 12.580**2 = 0
```

this helps a bit.

You've got three equations, and three unknowns.

The brute force method is to loop through x, y, and z values (over some domain of x, y, and z), and see how close all equations get to zero.

```
fa = -0.006683 x**2 - 0.06893 x + 56.73- z
fb = 0.002538 y**2 - 1.115 y + 56.73 - z
fc = (x-24.680)**2+(y-238.341)**2+(z+13.971)**2 - 12.580**2
```

Use a 'cost function', like cost=fa * fa + fb * fb + fc  * fc , and look for the minimum.

There are other methods, like the Nelder-Mead method, which can be used, and are more efficient.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method

Once you find a minimum, you can take your original search range, and make it finer, depending on what sort of accuracy you need.

@warped gives a nicer, more Pythonic solution, however, there is always the possibility there is *no* solution, or multiple solutions.  BTW, is this a geometry problem?  The last equation looks like the equation of a sphere.

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import math

def equations(p):
    x, y, z = p
    return (-0.006683 * x*x - 0.06893 * x + 56.73- z, \
            0.002538 * y*y - 1.115 * y + 56.73 - z, \
          (x-24.680)**2+(y-238.341)**2+(z+13.971)**2-12.580**2)

x, y, z =  fsolve(equations, (1,1,1))

print (equations((x,y,z)))

print(x,y,z)
```

Using the method noted in this question using SymPy (answered in nice detail by @Oscar Benjamin), [How to solve a pair of nonlinear equations using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739227/how-to-solve-a-pair-of-nonlinear-equations-using-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)

you can find other solutions in another way.  However, this method didn't find any solutions, at least with my first stab at it.

```
from sympy import *

x, y, z = symbols('x, y, z')
eq1 = Eq(-0.006683 * x * x - 0.06893 * x + 56.73- z, 0)
eq2 = Eq(0.002538 * y * y - 1.115 * y + 56.73 - z, 0)
eq3 = Eq((x-24.680)**2+(y-238.341)**2+(z+13.971)**2-12.580**2, 0)

sol = solve([eq1, eq2, eq3], [x, y,z])


print(sol)
print("")
if(len(sol)>1):
    soln = [tuple(v.evalf() for v in s) for s in sol]
    for idx, each in enumerate(soln):
        print(idx,each)
```

Comment: Yeah it is a geometry problem! The last equation is a sphere equation as you pointed out. I'll try the different things you suggested. Thanks !

Comment: Note that the initial conditions for the search in what was posted was (1,1,1); you may get different answers with different initial search parameters (like (100,100,100)).  Check the reference: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html#scipy.optimize.fsolve !

Comment: Is there any way/method that ables me to get all of the solutions of the system ?

Comment: Ah, that's another problem.  One way to try and solve this is to use different starting points for the initial conditions.  Since you are working in the x-y-z coordinate system, you could try 8 extremes (the points of a cube, say, (1000,1000,1000), (1000,1000,-1000), etc. as well as (0,0,0).  This won't tell you everything, but it might be a start.  For example, the intersection of a 2D circle with a 2D parabola might get you 0,1,2,3, or 4 solutions.  Much of this depends on the problem details.

Comment: Note the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739227/how-to-solve-a-pair-of-nonlinear-equations-using-python?noredirect=1&lq=1; SymPy can deliver more than one solution.

Comment: Got it ! It helped a lot ! Thank You !