# Solving for a single (non linear) equation in a for loop with substitution?

Tags: python, solver, nonlinear-optimization, equation-solving

I am trying to solve for a single (non linear) equation using **fsolve in a for loop**, however it doesn't seem to work in my code.

From previous assistance from [How to solve nonlinear equations using a for loop in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64096992/how-to-solve-nonlinear-equations-using-a-for-loop-in-python/64098305#64098305)
 I managed to get this right for solving for two or more equations, but could not get it to work for a single non linear equation.

***Note that N is the stepped range values we substitute in for using the for loop**

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np

f_curve_coefficients = [-7.14285714e-02, 1.96333333e+01, 6.85130952e+03]
S = [0.2122, 0, 0]

a2 = f_curve_coefficients[0]
a1 = f_curve_coefficients[1]
a0 = f_curve_coefficients[2]

s2 = S[0]
s1 = S[1]
s0 = S[2]


def f(variable):
    x = variable
    first_eq =a2*x**2+a1*N*x +a0*N**2-(s2*x**2+s1*x+s0)
    return [first_eq]

for N in range(1,6,1):
    
    roots = fsolve(f,20) # fsolve(equations, X_0)
    print(roots)
```

In Matlab we have a function called *fzero* which could solve this - not sure if Python has a similar function?

The solution doesn't have to be fsolve - just working on recommendations from users from python forums...

In advance thank you for all the assistance. Really don't know what I would do without stackoverflow!

Comment: remove you function `def f(variable): ...` and use `f = lambda x : a2*x**2+a1*N*x +a0*N**2-(s2*x**2+s1*x+s0)` instead. Running your code I get an exception, this change will solve it. You are alredy using `fsolve` from `scipy.optimize`, so yes there is a similar function. Which is your question ,can you clarify?

Comment: Carlo Zanocco - thanks for answering my question. By removing the def f(variable) part with the f = lambda solved it for me. I will read up on the f = lambda x: ... not familar with this notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change you code as follow:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np

f_curve_coefficients = [-7.14285714e-02, 1.96333333e+01, 6.85130952e+03]
S = [0.2122, 0, 0]

a2 = f_curve_coefficients[0]
a1 = f_curve_coefficients[1]
a0 = f_curve_coefficients[2]

s2 = S[0]
s1 = S[1]
s0 = S[2]

f = lambda x : a2*x**2+a1*N*x +a0*N**2-(s2*x**2+s1*x+s0)

for N in range(1,6,1):
    roots = fsolve(f, 20)
    print(roots)
```

Remove the function:

```
def f(variable):
    x = variable
    first_eq =a2*x**2+a1*N*x +a0*N**2-(s2*x**2+s1*x+s0)
    return [first_eq]
```

And convert it to:

```
f = lambda x : a2*x**2+a1*N*x +a0*N**2-(s2*x**2+s1*x+s0)
```

If you want to keep you original code, just correct it:

```
def f(variable):
    x = variable
    first_eq =a2*x**2+a1*N*x +a0*N**2-(s2*x**2+s1*x+s0)
    return first_eq
```

Your `return [first_eq]` return a list and generate the exception `Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.`

You can also simplify the code as follow:

```
def f(x):
    return a2*x**2+a1*N*x +a0*N**2-(s2*x**2+s1*x+s0)
```

Take a look to the [lambdas reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda)

`fsolve()` returns the roots of `f(x)` look [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html)