# Solving Non-Linear Equation in Python

Tags: nonlinear-functions

I have two equations with two unknowns but they seem to be quite non-linear. They are of the form,

C1 = (A1) * ((10)^(B1 * x)) * ((D1 * y)^(E1))

C2 = (A2) * ((10)^(B2 * x)) * ((D2 * y)^(E2))

I would like to solve for x and y and the rest are all constants. I have tried using 'SymPy' and 'solve' but the code seems to be running forever.

Comment: What are the unknowns here?

Comment: Have you tried something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/8739526/6328506 ?

Comment: This is exactly the link I am trying. I am passing the following to create the function: temp_soln = fsolve(equations(temp_a, temp_b, temp_c), (1, 1)) and my function ends with  'return [eq1, eq2]'. Here temp_a, temp_b, temp_c are some variables required to create the function. The function definition looks like 'def equations(a, b, c):' and I define the variable that I would like to solve for using x, y = symbols('x y'). But I get an error that tells me 'TypeError: 'list' object is not callable'.